# GitLab with relative URL on Apache (CentOS web server)

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, webserver, gitlab

I have a CentOS 7 server with an existing website (say mywebsite.com) hosted with Apache. I would like GitLab to be managed by Apache and not nginx, and with a realtive url with respect to the one of my website (say mywebsite.com/gitlab). Is this feasible with the GitLab omnibus pacakge?

*Edit:*
Some additional info about my configuration. Here is my apache main configuration file which should contain the information to resolve any request not matching any of the virtual hosts; I did not touch this file as far as GitLab installation is concerned.

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**
[pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/ZSepbuED)

The following is the configuration file I added in order to make apache resolve the virtual host (still trying to understand if a relative url virtual host is possible) with GitLab; I followed [this guide](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/doc/settings/nginx.md#using-a-non-bundled-web-server) for Apache 2.4 and GitLab Omnibus (the default recipe is [this one](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-recipes/blob/master/web-server/apache/gitlab-omnibus-apache24.conf)).

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/gitlab.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com/gitlab
    ServerSignature Off

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    AllowEncodedSlashes NoDecode

    <Location />
        Require all granted
        ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
        ProxyPassReverse http://mywebsite.com/gitlab
    </Location>

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
    RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

    DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

    ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
    ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
    ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
    ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
    ErrorDocument 503 /503.html

    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common_forwarded
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mywebsite_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mywebsite_forwarded.log common_forwarded
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mywebsite_access.log combined env=!dontlog
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mywebsite.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, this is the configuration of GitLab Omnibus package; I changed the gitlab workhorse port, disabled nginx and set apache as external user for the web server. As far as the external user is concerned, I did not use www-data because no such user exists on my machine (gitlab-ctl reconfigure also gave errors if I tried to use www-data). I imagine apache is the correct one, due to the "User apache" directive in httpd.conf, but I am not absolutely sure about that.

**/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```
external_url 'http://mywebsite.com/gitlab'

gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"

web_server['external_users'] = ['apache']
nginx['enable'] = false
```

With such configuration my website is not working: every page shows the 503 GitLab error "Whoops, GitLab is currently unavailable. Try refreshing the page, or going back and attempting the action again."; what could be the reason for that?
Note that if I remove the gitlab.conf file and reload httpd, the normal website works fine. Also, if I disable apache and only run GitLab (with nginx) with default configuration on the relative url, everything works fine too; I just can't put the two things togeter, relative url and apache instead of nginx.

Comment: You seem to be looking for this bit of the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server

Comment: I tried to follow the documentation and everything seems to be fine, but when I browse the website, after having followed those steps, every page seems to "belong" to GitLab and shows a 503 error, including the relative url mywebsite.com/gitlab

Comment: Perhaps you can share your configuration here and point out what works and what doesn't. It's hard to debug an Apache problem without looking at the configuration file.

Comment: You're totally right, sorry for that. I updated the post

Comment: Sorry for the delayed update. I think the problem here is that the new virtual host hijacks your existing server configuration, making all the URLs owned by GitLab. I believe you can instead confine your changes to the `/gitlab` URL using the `Location` directive. I'll try and reproduce this problem myself.

Comment: No, problem, thank you for the interest! I got informed about the `Location` directive, and actually found that <Location "/"> _is an easy way to apply a configuration to the entire server_, which is the case of my __gitlab.conf__. Maybe the guide was not meant for GitLab installation on a relative URL.

Comment: **UPDATE** For anyone with similar problems, I continued documenting on the `Location` directive (so, thanks a lot @Haxiel for the input!) and found [this solution](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/gitlab-on-raspberry-as-subdirectory-on-apache/2719). I didn't have to add a `VirtualHost` to _wrap_ my default host: indeed I left it as it is in the **httpd.conf**, while I substituted the whole content of **gitlab.conf** with the `Location` directive for GitLab specified in the linked solution.
Everything works fine now!

Comment: Great to see that you've found a solution. You should write that up as an answer, so that this QA stands on its own without being dependent on the link you've provided. Also, then I can upvote it :-).

Comment: Done, thank you again for your support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is working on a CentOS 7 web server with Apache 2.4.6 and GitLab 11.9.4 installed by means of GitLab Omnibus package. The server is running on http but it should be easily transferrable to https.

I suppose to start from a clean installation of Apache managing only one single host on the domain *mywebsite.com* (no virtual host). Clean installation of GitLab Omnibus package is also supposed ([official guide](https://about.gitlab.com/install/#centos-7)). For the sake of completeness, here is the **httpd.conf** file, main configuration file of Apache.
It contains the directives to listen to port 80 and direct all the requests to the main domain *mywebsite.com* to the directory specified by `DocumentRoot` directive, which is `/var/www/html`; in my case such directory contains a WordPress instance.

**/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** 
[httpd.conf on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/0ZTF1vjM)

Now, before editing GitLab configuration, be sure to stop all the related services with `sudo gitlab-ctl stop`.
To enable GitLab to work on a relative URL, as a subdirectory of the main domain *mywebsite.com*, first thing first is to install GitLab on a relative URL; in particular, you have to modify the `external_url` directive of **gitlab.rb** setting `'http://mywebsite.com/gitlab'` as argument. Then, nginx, which is the default web server bundled in GitLab Omnibus, has to be disabled; the external user for the web server has to be set to `apache` (external user for Apache is `www-data` in most distro, but `apache` for CentOS 7); GitLab workhorse has to be set to listen to tcp since Apache can only use http sockets; in the following it is supposed that GitLab workhorse listens to port 8181, which is also to be set. To keep the GitLab installation simple, I also disabled the CI/CD functionalities for pipeline (with the `gitlab_rails` directive), but this rather depends on your needs. 
See the official GitLab Omnibus documentation to know more about [configuring a relative URL](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-a-relative-url-for-gitlab) and [using a non-bundled web server](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#using-a-non-bundled-web-server).
The resulting configuration file for GitLab should be something like the following.

**/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb**

```
external_url 'http://mywebsite.com/gitlab'

gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "tcp"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "127.0.0.1:8181"

web_server['external_users'] = ['apache']
nginx['enable'] = false

gitlab_rails['gitlab_default_projects_features_builds'] = false
```

Now run a `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.
Let's go back to Apache configuration: now GitLab is set-up, but we have to redirect all the requests to *http://mywebsite.com/gitlab* to the actual GitLab server. Most solutions I found suggest to use subfolder with virtual hosts, but this appears not to work with GitLab. The solution is to use the `Location` directive; you can either append such configuration in the main apache configuration file **httpd.conf** or create a new .conf file and place it in **/etc/httpd/conf.d/**, so that it will be included automatically (but be sure that your **httpd.conf** contains the directive `IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`). The configuration is the following.

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/gitlab.conf**

```
Header add Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=15768000;includeSubdomains"

<Location /gitlab>
  Require all granted

  #Allow forwarding to gitlab-workhorse
  ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8181
  ProxyPassReverse http://mywebsite.com/gitlab

  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/uploads/.*
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8181%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,NE]

  ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
  ErrorDocument 422 /422.html
  ErrorDocument 500 /500.html
  ErrorDocument 502 /502.html
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Be sure to modify the argument of `<Location /gitlab>` basing on the relative URL on which you want GitLab to be reacheable.
The configuration is now complete, run `systemctl reload httpd` to reconfigure Apache and restart GitLab with `sudo gitlab-ctl restart`. One more thing: be sure to allow Apache to use the http sockets: `sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1`.